# How to remove elements from python class list

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python oops. I am trying to remove an object (trying to remove all the student with mid = 1)from a class list.

for example -

`stdents = [[[1], 'y', 'r'], [[2, 3], 'y', 'w'], [[1], 'z', 'r']]`

I want to remove all id which contains 1.

here is my code -

```
class StudentTable:
    def _init_(self, idList, name, state):
        self.idList = []
        self.name = name
        self.state = state
stdents = []
student = StudentTable([1], 'y', 'r')
stdents.append(student)
student = StudentTable([2, 3], 'y', 'w')
stdents.append(student)
student = StudentTable([1], 'z', 'r')
stdents.append(student)

print(stdents[0].name)
print(stdents[1].name)
print(stdents[2].name)

mid = 1

for i in range(len(stdents)):
    if mid in stdents[i].idList:
        # del stdents[i]
        stdents.remove(mid)

print(stdents)
```

But it's not removing.

Even I tried `del` but not working.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Khush

Comment: What is `trans_id`?

Comment: @DYZ sorry, updated.

Comment: `list.remove` removes by value, not by position. `mid` is always equal to 1, but the list `students` does not have such an element.

Comment: @DYZ so should i iterate idList ? & remove one by one if matches ?

Comment: I am trying to learn coding that's where i got this issue. I am not getting how to resolve.

Comment: @DYZ please guide

Comment: @DYZ i tried. its `remove`, `del` or `pop` but nothing works.

Comment: look up list filtering, there are multiple ways to do it but as DYZ said, any decent tutorial should cover this. One simple way is to create a second list and only add those elements that fit your condition.

Answer (score 0):

actually there is a simple mistake in line 3.

it should be `self.idList = idList` instead of `self.idList = []`

```
class StudentTable:
    def __init__(self, idList, name, state):
        self.idList = idList
        self.name = name
        self.state = state

stdents = []

student1 = StudentTable([1], 'a', 'r')
stdents.append(student1)

student2 = StudentTable([3], 'b', 'w')
stdents.append(student2)

student3 = StudentTable([1], 'c', 'r')
stdents.append(student3)

#print(stdents[0].name)
#print(stdents[1].name)
#print(stdents[2].name)

mid = 1

for i in (stdents):
    #print(i.idList,i)
    if mid in i.idList:
        stdents.remove(i)

    
print(stdents)
```